# Linking a resource file to an existing .NET assembly using Assembly Linker

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, linker

I am trying to link the file `name.ext` to `assembly.dll` using the [AL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx) (Assembly Linker) to mimic what can be done in C++ using the [/ASSEMBLYLINKRESOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztd4k98t.aspx) option.

The syntax I am using is the following:

```
al.exe assembly.dll /link:name.ext
```

and I get the following error:

*ALINK: error AL1017: No target filename was specified*

I also tried:

```
al.exe assembly.dll /out:outAssembly.dll /link:name.ext
```

getting the following error:

*ALINK: warning AL1020: Ignoring included assembly 'assembly.dll'*

*ALINK: error AL1019: Metadata failure while creating assembly -- The system cannot find the file specified.*

What I am doing wrong? What is the correct syntax to obtain the resource link?

Thanks.

Comment: The assembly linker requires .netmodule files as input, it can't use a dll.  The equivalent C# compiler option is /linkresource.  Not supported by the IDE.  Hacking msbuild is proposed in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5854230/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Assembly Linker generates a file that has an assembly manifest from one or more files that are either modules or resource files. A module is an intermediate language (IL) file that does not have an assembly manifest.

`assembly.dll` can not be the source of Assembly Linker because it already *is* an assembly with manifest. So you get this

*ALINK: warning AL1020: Ignoring included assembly 'assembly.dll'*

Comment: I think I cannot use `ILMerge` because the file I am trying to link is not a .NET assembly, it's a generic file I simply need to be copied to output folder when using original `assembly.dll`...

Comment: you are right, i just read its documentation and find it could't do that.

Comment: then why not make a Setup project to deploy the file? AL is for embedded resources.

Comment: In C++ is possible and it looked like the same thing could be done by AssemblyLinker. Deploy the file is not an option for us.