# Usage of csc linkresource option

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, msbuild

I have .net assembly which uses native dll. IIS copies files to 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' folder. And I want IIS copies dll together with native dll. I tried to use manifest dependencies but without success. I heard that I can user csc option **-linkresource** for native dll, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/linkresource-compiler-option)

> Compile A.cs into a DLL, link to a native DLL N.dll, and put the
>   output in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). In this example, both A.dll
>   and N.dll will reside in the GAC.
>
> csc -linkresource:N.dll -t:library A.cs   gacutil -i A.dll

I want to use this option but

> This compiler option is unavailable in Visual Studio and cannot be
>   changed programmatically.

But they forced me do not use visual studio project and build it by csc directly. It is a too robust task.

Can I change the project file to accomplish this task?

I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625129/linkresource-in-visual-studio-2010) this article but it is outdated and does not contain any useful information. I use 2019 Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was too simple for the 2019 Studio!

I just added several lines to the project file and ...voila!

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <LinkResource Include="..\Debug\NativeDll64.dll">
      <Link>NativeDll64.dll</Link>
    </LinkResource>
    <LinkResource Include="..\Debug\NativeDll32.dll">
      <Link>NativeDll32.dll</Link>
    </LinkResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And these two files now are copied to GAC or Temporary ASP.NET Files along with the managed assembly.

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution for your issue, please consider marking it as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help share the useful info to others :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're running your application in IIS, apart from overwriting the `CoreCompile` target, maybe you can also consider turning off `shadow copying`.

Set `shadowCopyBinAssemblies` to `false` in `web.config`.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
```

And then it will load assemblies from `bin` folder instead of `Temporary` folder. And it's easier to [copy native assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864404/10910450) to bin folder. Many topics about msbuild can give you help. More details about shadow copying please refer to [this blog](http://faithlife.codes/blog/2013/05/using-native-dlls-from-asp-net-apps/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am interested in shadow copying because it makes easier to upgrade installation. So, it is the solution to the last resort.