# Connecting to embedded SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite

What would be the connection string for one to connect to an SQLite database file, added/embedded to the project?

I wish to add my database as an "Existing File..." to my project, bundle it up in the output *.exe and be able to get data from it. However using a connection string of "Data Source=mydb.s3db" or "Data Source=~\mydb.s3db" doesn't work.

I can open the db file in question in the "SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox" but from there I wan't able to figure out how to get any connection string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I embed a SQLite Database in a .NET DLL and then use it from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791198/how-can-i-embed-a-sqlite-database-in-a-net-dll-and-then-use-it-from-c)

Comment: @dymanoid, well, it sort of is asking the same question. But seeing as not one of the answerers could read past 5 words nothing is ever mentioned about connecting to an embedded database. How should I proceed now that I could not find information on the Internet and that question is sort of the same as mine but has -1 useful information?