# UWP Secured file location for Database

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

currently I'm working with an application using ionic framework and testing it as of now as UWP application. 
May I know where should I put my sqlite database file where the other window users can't see or access it except the application that created it?

Thank you.

Comment: hey, i dont know about the framework but c# projects have the possibility to add items as embedded resources., you can also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791198/how-can-i-embed-a-sqlite-database-in-a-net-dll-and-then-use-it-from-c

Comment: hi @Isparia, Thank you for this. But, is this will  still  rewrite-able to the application?

Comment: sadly not but if you really want make sure that the database is not found, you might want to consider using an in memory database. But this requires logic to recreate the database every time. what could work for you might be a mix off both. 
1. Create a Class which generates your database for in memory,
2. add fallback data as an xml/csv which is embedded,
3. populate the database from the embedded data. 
4. keep a binary file which you encrypt and update on application exist
5. use the file from 4. to update your in memory db on startup