# Get File From an Assembly

Tags: c#

I want to read a file path from the following structure

The Structure is like :  AssemblyName -> MyFiles (Folder) -> Text.txt

Here I want to get the path of the Text.txt. Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a file embedded in the assembly. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly). The first answer explains how to set up an embedded file, as well as how to get it from code.

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
string assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);
string textPath = Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, "MyFiles", "Test.txt");
string text = File.ReadAllText(textPath);
```

...just to split it up some...but you could write it all in one line needless to say...

alternatively, if your Environment.CurrentDirectory is already set to the directory of your executing assembly's location, you could just do

```
File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine("MyFiles", "Text.txt"));
```

Comment: I am getting an Exception, "Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\taks\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Console Applications\GetFilesFromAssembly\GetFilesFromAssembly\bin\Debug\MyFiles\Test.txt'"

Comment: @JeffN825 I think he's got an embedded file, not a file in the same directory as the assembly.

Comment: This would not work if the file were in the library's folder instead of the executing assembly's folder.  I have yet to find an approach that works for library sub folders except for the embedded resource approach.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff has covered how you get the path, wrt your comment on his answer is the file you want to open actually included in your project output?

Under the properties pane for the relevant file look at the `Copy to Output Directory` option - it generally defaults to `Do not copy`.  You will want to set it to `Copy Always` or `Copy if Newer` if you want to include a file in the output directory with your compiled program.

As a general note you should always wrap any IO in an appropriate try catch block or use the static `File.Exists(path)` method to check whether a file exists

Comment: The issue is I cannot copy this file to Output Directory, I have to access this file from the mentioned hierarchy.

Comment: thanks Eric for the suggestion, It is working, I have embedded the as a resource

Comment: @user1238374, what "mentioned hierarchy" is? Your first level is "AssemblyName -> " which everyone understands differently (embedded resource in the assembly, path relative to assembly, maybe even path relative to assembly in the GAC), please clarify what you mean (and possibly what you **actually** want to achieve).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  Assembly contains a Folder name "MyFiles" which in turn contains a file name "Text.txt" . Now this assembly will be referred by another assembly in which I have to read the contain of "Text.txt" file.