# Embed Text File in Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource

I was trying to embed a Text File into my application in my Resources file. I was following this question post awhile back;

[How to embed a text file in a .NET assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly)

I added my Text file into Resources.resx, but can't understand how to call it in code. As you can see the OP had the same problem and managed to get it working using `My.Resources.TEXTFILENAME` as opposed to the top answers suggestion of `Resources.TEXTFILENAME`. Unfortunately neither is being recognised in my application and I have tried adding usings but VS isn't suggesting any. Writing `Resources` by itself, it recognises it as a ResourceDictionary and FrameworkElement.Resources, but no text files... Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the text file to your project, then define it as content (`Build Action`=`Content`) and `Copy always` to Output.

If you have an installer for your project (standard installer) you can setup the file system so the installer will copy the text file automatically.

to get the folder where the application is running, i use this :

`Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location);`

If you're using the new installer (ClicOnce) i cannot help you, but i wish you luck :=)

Comment: I'm actually not using any installer. Just using the exe I generate.

Comment: But won't that just copy the file to the output directory and not embed it?

Comment: @Nenotlep : I guess you're right. I must be : Build Action=Resource /  and do not copy . I'll update if you confirm, do not hesitate to post an answer if you can bring some intel.

Answer (score 17):

Embedding textual resources like this seems to work (visual c# express):

1. Open your project properties 
   [image]
2. Browse to resources, click add new and select to create or add existing, whichever is true. 
   [image]
3. A wild resources folder appears 
   [image]
4. Use them like this:

   ```
   string foo = global::[ProjectName].Properties.Resources.Muistio;
   string bar = global::[ProjectName].Properties.Resources.asd;
   ```

The resource Build action is **None** and Copy to output directory is **Do not copy**.

It would be great if someone could verify this, it works when the exe is transferred to my server 2k8, but I'd still want independent verification. Especially since ResourceHacker did not see the strings.

Comment: +1 Useful screenshots. Also, a wild resources folder... brilliant.

Comment: Yes but you can't stream it. You have to use the property @Nenotlep mentions, or use ResourceManager.GetString(name) but that yields a string in Unicode - potentially twice larger than the file.

Comment: This worked for me in VS 2017. Screenshots are pretty useful.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2019....

Answer (score 3):

If the file is small, the project resource file can be used as described by others, but that way the file can only be retrieved as an Unicode string, potentially/probably twice larger than the original file and loaded into memory at once in its entirety.

The way referred to in the original question is to just put the text file somewhere in your project, select it in Solution Explorer, hit F4 to show Properties, then set **Build Action** to **Embedded resource** and leaving **Copy to output directory** at **Do not copy**.

This is the same as adding to your .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\TextFile.txt"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then you will need either an instance of the correct `Assembly`, or an `IFileProvider` to access those resources by name.

Through Assembly:

```
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name)
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(name)
```

these names are akin class names, dot-separated. If your project is `NamespaceName.ProjectName`, the resource file is in the `Resources` subfolder and called `TextFile.txt`, the resource name is going to be

```
NamespaceName.ProjectName.Resources.TextFile.txt
```

There is an overload for `GetManifestResourceStream` that takes a type so you can do

```
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
    typeof(Program),
    "Resources.TextFile.txt")
```

to never depend on the default namespace or project output file name.

The downside to these is that they don't appear to work from the watches window. You might get an exception

```
System.ArgumentException "Cannot evaluate a security function."
```

In that case just write that code some place where you can execute it at will - in a static method for example. So that code runs from your assembly, not the debugger.

And through `IFileProvider`:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
var fp = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(Program).Assembly);
// get all resources as an enumerable
foreach (var fileInfo in fp.GetDirectoryContents(""))
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {fileInfo.Name}, Length: {fileInfo.Length}, ...");
// get a specific one by name
var stream = fp.GetFileInfo("Resources.TextFile.txt").CreateReadStream();
```

Being an `IFileProvider`, you could probably try to host .NET Core websites from pure embedded resources.

Answer (score 2):

Using the .ResX resources is slightly different to embedding a text file into your assembly.  For the latter, you want to check its properties and make it an *EmbeddedResource* (ie, there's no need to add anything to a ResX file, just drop the text file into your VS Project).  To retrieve it, use this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name);
```

To get the correct value for the *name* parameter, call *GetManifestResourceNames()* and inspect the results.

Comment: Hmm... So I used `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Explaination.txt");` and Explaination.txt is in my debug folder, but this line done not appear to do anything. Thoughts?

Comment: Bare in mind I just want to open the Text file in notepad for example.