# Where to put the external file in a project

Tags: c#

I have a dataset file a.txt where I want to include as part of the visual studio 2010 C# project. Where should I put it(need your suggestion), and how should I read it with FileInfo (as project might move around the PC by different developers, it is not good to have hardcoded path)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in /resources or some dir you create from root.  Then you can read it at runtime from

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + "\\resources"
```

or you can embed is a resource, then you can use

```
Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string)
```

more info on that here 
 [How to embed a text file in a .NET assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly)