# Embed Text Files in a .NET Assembly or Executable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to embed a text file in a .NET assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly)

I have a c# winforms application that use several text files.

I would like to somehow embed those files either into the exe or dlls, so that they cannot be seen by the user when the application is deployed.

Can visual studio do something like that?

Comment: Look up "embedded resource"

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly

Comment: John's right. Resources are exactly what you need.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With text files you can also proceed as following:

1. Double click your `Properties` -> `Resources.resx` file to open the resource designer.
2. From the first small drop down on the top, select "Files" as resource type.
3. Click on `Add Resource` -> `Add Existing File...` and select your text files.

Let's say that the TXT you added was called `Foo.txt`... you can just access it's content like so:

```
String foo = Properties.Resources.Foo;
```

Then you can also change te file names inside the resource designer and they will be automatically refactored in your code. From the `Resources` directory, where they are now located in your project, you can also edit them.
I just recommend you to keep their access level as `internal`.

Comment: Yep man, you preceeded me by some seconds! ;P

Comment: For me it also required to restart the Visual Studio after adding the files to the resources

Comment: it doesn't work on Linux though.

Comment: `var xx = Properties.Resources.xx;
Console.Write(xx);` the output is `..\Resource\xx.txt;System.String, mscorlib, ....
`

Comment: made a question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57506170/631527

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I do it:

1. In the solution Explorer, right-click on Properies/Resources.resx.
2. Choose "View Designer".
3. You *can* use the "Add Resource" button, but I often just drag the file right onto the designer window.
4. Visual Studio will perform code generation, such that you can access your file using `Properties.Resources.YourFileName`.

Be wary: Visual Studio will *copy* your chosen file into your project's Resources folder. It will not create a link to wherever the file was originally stored.

Comment: Doesn't work on Linux https://stackoverflow.com/q/57506170/631527