# How do I read the contents of an embedded text file?

Tags: c#

I have a text file `data.txt` that's embedded in my solution (as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly)).

How do I read the contents of this file as a string?  I'm imagining something like this:

```
 string data = Resources["data.txt"];
```

but that's not the way to do it.

Comment: Beyond the many duplicates, the answer to your question is also found in one of the answers for the question you linked.

Comment: It looks like the answer there requires the resource file to be exported to the target folder.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Joe: I don't think it does. Look at [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292), linked from an answer in that question.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the file as a resource you should be able to access it like this:

```
Properties.Resources.data
```

Or alternatively if you set the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy always`/`Copy if newer`, you can do something like:

```
using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open("Resources/data.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
   // do amazing stuff here ...            
}
```

Comment: Do I need some kind of `using` statement to use `Properties`?

Comment: It's part of your default app namespace. You shouldn't need to.