# Displaying row count from SQL server to program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, ssms

I am working on a program on C# VS 2015. In my program, there is a big text display box that generates message when I click a certain button to indicate an action is being performed.

Anyway, I have a SQL script where it has queries for `COUNT` for some tables. I can run that script through my program. However , since row count displays total number of rows for a table  and can only be viewed inside SQL server. I was wondering is there a way to execute my script and also display the ROW COUNTS inside my program at the big text display box?

Here is a snippet of my code to run that SQL script:

```
    /*  open sql connection to execute SQL script: Row count script*/
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DIRECTORY OF THE SCRIPT);
            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(con));
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
            Display("ABCDG"); -- to display message on text display
            con.Close();



        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}", Environment.NewLine));
        textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} MainPage_Load() exception - {1}{2}", _strThisAppName, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine));
        Display(ex.Message + ""); -- display message to textbox
        textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}", Environment.NewLine));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} MainPage_Load() exception - {1}", _strThisAppName, ex.Message));


    }
```

Here is a snapshot of my program:

```
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKP99.png
```

Comment: and what is the script in `ExecuteNonQuery(script);`??

Comment: the script just contains a list of row count. for example, select count(*) from table A , select count(*) from table B , etc etc

Comment: A_Name_Does_Not_Matter Can you clarify how to achieve this?

Comment: Just use `ExecuteScalar`: `int numOfRows = (int)server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteScalar(script);`.

Comment: `var numRows = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);`
(documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of rows from sql table in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160928/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-from-sql-table-in-c)

Comment: Wait, do you want to get the row counts (i.e. the number of rows affected by the query), or the results of a `COUNT` aggregate function within a SQL `SELECT` statement?

Comment: basically you run a number of queries using ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: mjwills, this is not a duplicate as that thread is just asking to get the row count but in my case, it's executing a script to return row count.

Comment: Diado I just want to get the row counts return to the display box. For example , if you run that script in SQL server, you shall get Table A : 200 . Table B: 400 , ...... I want it to display on my program.

Comment: You may see my edited post for the snapshot of my program

Comment: I have added an answer for your situation.

Comment: you there??????

Comment: sunil chat room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple queries in your script file, then you should enhance your script with `@rowsAffected` variable as shown in T-SQL below. Then, in your C# code you will need to call *ExecuteScalar* to get the detailed rows affected by your script.

```
**Script file with @rowsAffected variable logic**

--add following variable at start of your script
DECLARE @rowsAffected VARCHAR(2000);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] ([ProductName]) VALUES ('sun1'),('sun2'),('sun3');

--after each query that you want to track, include the following line
SET @rowsAffected = 'Products : ' + CAST(@@rowcount AS varchar(20));

UPDATE [dbo].[newTable]   SET [ColB] = 'b' ,[ColC] = 'd',[ColD] = 'e'  ,[ColE] = 'f'  WHERE ColA='a';

 --after each query that you want to track, include the following line
SET @rowsAffected = @rowsAffected + ', newTable : ' + CAST(@@rowcount AS varchar(20));

-- add the query below at end of your script 
SELECT @rowsAffected;
```

You will have to read the text from your script file, as you are doing in your code, and then create a command object using the text read from file before executing the code in snippet below.

**C# code to execute above script**

```
string rowsAffected =(string) command.ExecuteScalar();
//you can now use rowsAffected variable in any way you like
//it will contain something like Table1 : 4, Table2 : 6
```

**Detailed C# code using your original code**

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DIRECTORY OF THE SCRIPT);
        string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(script, con);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string rowsAffected =(string) command.ExecuteScalar();
            Display( rowsAffected);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            Display(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160002/discussion-on-answer-by-sunil-displaying-row-count-from-sql-server-to-program).

Answer (score 0):

As Tetsuya Yamamoto said in his comment, what you are looking for is the use of the ExecuteScalar method. Your code change may look something like the below

```
     int numOfRows = (int)server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteScalar(script);
     string displayText =  numOfRows.ToString();
     Display(displayText); -- to display message on text display
     con.Close();
```

The cast ToString is just for safety purposes as I am unsure how your Display will handle an int value

Comment: Yes, but OP suggests he's running several count queries in that script, not just one select count.

Comment: I completely know this is one of the way it could be done but not in my situation. You can see the snapshot of my program. On the left side, is a big text box display. My goal is to create a button and when pressed, it will run this script , say script name is countrow.sql.  Then, inside the script , it has many queries for counting records for different tables but that's not the issue. I just want the result to display in real time on the text box , just like how it display on the result screen in SQL server when you run a count query. ExecuteScarlar method will not do this.