# Including readme file to the compiled program

Tags: c#, attachment, readme

I have a small code that does some recalculations using text data provided. I also have written a readme file with the description of features and 'how-to' instructions. The main idea is to make the program standalone that is only one .exe file.

I did some googling, but found only how to work with external files or create installers.

The question is how to include a text file into the compiled .exe file and how to open it with a button click.

So far I found how to embed a resource and read it as a stream using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)`.
 Though, when I try read it through `StreamReader` it returns `System.ArgumentNullException`

`Stream streamS = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(ProjectName.Properties.Resources.Readme);
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(streamS);
string text = rdr.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed a text file in a .NET assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

Add it as an Embedded Resource. You can then access it with `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`. If you want to show it in a window in your application, that's sufficient; if you want to open it in an external program, like Notepad, you'll have to extract it to a temporary file (`Path.GetTempFileName`), then start Notepad.exe with `Process.Start`.

Comment: I see it is indeed done using `Assembly`, but I'm stuck at `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` returning "Can't read memory". The file I embedded is in the Resources folder with "Embedded resource" property

Comment: @MrCheatak add your full code and the full exception to your question?

Comment: Just added where I was stuck with `Assembly`, but succeeded it another way around by using just  `string text = ProjectName.Properties.Resources.Readme;`