# Deleting Created Temp FIles

Tags: c#, .net, temporary-files

In C# or Jscript.NET is it necessary (or better to) delete files created in the folder returned by System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() or is it acceptable to wait for the system to delete them (if this ever happens)?

Comment: Its best for your application to delete the temp files it creates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of how your program will work, it makes no difference.

The issue is one of cluttering the filesystem with many files in a folder - the more files in a folder, the slower it will be to read it.

There is also a chance of running out of disk space if the files are not deleted.

In general, if your software creates temporary files, it should cleanup after itself (that is, delete the files once they are no longer in use).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you always clean up the mess you create. "Temp" files tend to hang around for a long time unless the user is savvy enough to use cleanup tools like CCleaner.

Note: This does add the complexity (and potential bugs) of having to remember all the temp files you've created in order to clean them up, but I think it's worth it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400391/237942) by Mr. Gravell has an easy way to take care of that issue.