# Error deleting a text file from a folder

Tags: c#, file

I am working on an C# application which  creates a text file with some data in it, saves it in a folder, sends it to a list of email addresses and deletes the file from that location but when I call the File.Delete() it throws me an exception saying file cannot be accessed as it is being used by another process. That is because the file is being used by the email service and trying to delete so, its an obvious exception but when I tried to a Delay between two function calls, it still threw me an exception

```
  _dailyBargainReport.sendRejectionReport(servername, fromAddress, password, sub, bodyofmail, rejectionReportPath);

             Task.Delay(20000);
            File.Delete(rejectionReportPath);
```

Comment: I'm going to assume that `sendRejectionReport` has no using statements within. Everything that implements `IDisposable` needs to be wrapped in a using statement.

Comment: What does `.sendRejectionReport` look like? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: please show the code that you are using to create the file

Comment: @ChaosPandion No it doesn't

Comment: As a side-note, your `Task.Delay` doesn't help because you're not awaiting the task. Either do this `await Task.Delay(2000)` or simply block the thread `Thread.Sleep(2000)`

Comment: @dcastro. I tried using Thread.Sleep, it didnt work either

Comment: What is this omnious sendRejectionReport method? Does the deletion of the file still fails if you don't call that method (i.e., is the problem *really* related to calling sendRejectionReport, or is there perhaps something else going on)?

Comment: The real solution is to tell us what `sendRejectionReport` does and figuring out a way to signal that it's done with the file. Failing that, you could slap a bandaid on it with something like `Task.Delay(20000).ContinueWith(() => File.Delete(rejectionReportPath));`

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that you aren't calling the `Dispose` method on `FileStream`

```
using (FileStream f = File.Open("example.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    //do your operations
}
File.Delete(rejectionReportPath);
```

using statment always call `Dispose` so is equivalent to

```
try{
   FileStream f = File.Open("example.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
}
finally{
   ((IDisposable)f).Dispose();
}
//delete file here
```

**update**

try in this way to wait the function

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        _dailyBargainReport.sendRejectionReport(servername, fromAddress, password, sub, bodyofmail, rejectionReportPath);
    })
    .ContinueWith(() =>
    {
        File.Delete(rejectionReportPath);
    }).Wait();
```

In this way you are sure that `Delete` function is called after the end of `sendRejectionReport`.
Remembar to call `Dispose` inside `sendRejectionReport` function

Comment: It is not because the file is opened but it is because the file being used by sendRejectionReport function

Comment: Using the new updated answer, it neither sends the email nor deletes the file

Comment: are you debugging the code? Are your functions called?

Comment: Yes I am debugging the code and the functions and rightly called

Comment: has your parameters the right values?

Comment: I've updated my answer adding `.Wait()` let me know

Answer (score 0):

When creating the file, you could create it with a flag to be deleted when the process closes. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/400433/3846861